# JPA pagination query becomes slower with every subsequent call

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, garbage-collection

Project has Spring Boot with JPA. We have a table **vehicle** with 1m+ records. Table has an indexed field *type*.

We have a use case, where we want to fetch all the records by type. For each type, we get all the vehicle records, then for next type, then for next and so on.

Since there are 1m+ records, we are fetching the records for each type with the batch size of 1000. We also apply a filter with type column.

**VehicleRepository.java**

```
Page<VehicleRecord> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
```

**VehicleService.java**

```
for (String type: vehicleTypes) {

  Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1000, Sort.by("updated_at").ascending());
  Page<VehicleRecord> vehicles = null;

  do {
    vehicles = vehicleRepository.findByType(type, pageable);
    // do something with vehicles
    pageable = pageable.next();
  } while (vehicles.hasNext());

}
```

For the sake of understanding, assume there are 5 types of records:

1. A - 0 vehicles
2. B - 100000 vehicles
3. C - 0 vehicles
4. D - 0 vehicles
5. E - 0 vehicles

Problem:

1. In this, when fetching data for A, findByType completes in < 100ms. which is good.
2. When fetching for B though, first fetch with LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0 takes ~200ms. But it is downhill from here, with increase in OFFSET value, time also increases. By the time LIMIT is 1000 and OFFSET 90000, findByType takes 6000-7000ms.
3. What is further confusing is that after data is fetched for B, rest of the types (C, D & E) each take 3000-4000ms, when they have 0 data.

I am not sure what is happening here. I read somewhere that it is because of high OFFSET value that the method is taking so much time. But that does not explain why the method would take so much time for C, D, and E.

Any inputs would be helpful. Thanks

**Edit 1: Profiling results (Visual VM)**

1. SQL queries are executing normally, they take hardly 150-200ms, even for high offset values.
2. This is unexpected, that the vehicles collection keeps adding vehicle records to it after each iteration (observed this in memory section of profiler). I expected "live object" count to remain to max 1000, because that's what our limit size is. But after each iteration, it keeps adding 1000 records to it. Even after performing manual GC from profiler, it won't free that memory, until all the iterations for for loop are complete.

Comment: Maybe entity manager is not cleared? Maybe there is an attempt to lookup things in the cache. Is this done in single transaction?

Comment: How to figure that out? @Antoniossss

Comment: You have not provided enough information, but based on your observation I would suspect that pagination actually reads and fetches all the prior records. To get a better understanding, enable logging of SQL statements and then try to run those statements directly with the database. There should be no rows returned before ones that you are actually asking for. Second thing to check is the design and health of indexes used for this query.

Comment: I printed and checked the queries and they seem to be working fine. Need to check health of the indexex @jurez

Comment: what happens when you loop backwards? (e -> a)

Comment: @xerx593 same result

Comment: same: so E-to-C takes long, and A <100ms? (...1. why use  pagination, when we (anyways) want to read all. 2. some (sql/jpa)indices could help/improve (updated_at, type, both,...)

Comment: 2 more cents: what about comparing offset and keyset pagination? maybe that could also explain some of the slowdown? https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: @xerx593 E-C takes less time, A takes 3000ms

Comment: Try profiling, but this will likely be a DB issue resulting from the query used and the amount of data. As the article fladdimir shows, offset allows the DB so skip to the end, but most DBs still have to process everything in the query to know where to skip to. Generic tools like 'PageRequest' don't know about the entity or what was read so far, so must use offset. To get better performance, you'd have to know something about the last entry read in, and use that data in skipping ahead in an ordered list. Not something easy to do in stateless REST environments though.

Comment: @fladdimir I changed to code to work with WHERE type = ? AND id > ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 instead of WHERE type = ? ORDER BY updated_at LIMIT 1000 ORDER ?. But for some reason it is still behaving the same way. Is it possible that there is some kind of caching going on?

Comment: @bob did you run the plain sql queries directly against the db, just to be certain whether the type of pagination does really not explain the observed performance differences?

Comment: I ran plain sequel queries against DB. Something like select * from vehicle where type = 'C' ORDER BY updated_at ASC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 95000. It takes less time 1500-2000ms compared to what it takes in JPA. In JPA, by the time pagination reaches  90000+ offset value, it takes 6000-7000ms @fladdimir

Comment: @Chris I tried profiling, the queries are running normally, do not take much time, always < 200ms, even for high offsets (90,000+). Another thing I noticed during profiling was that after each iteration, the "live objects" count for VehicleRecord list increases by 1000. I expected it to stay at 1000, but it keeps increasing by 1000 everytime. Even if we perform Manual Garbage collection using profiler, it does not remove the collection from memory, until all the iterations are complete.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying about your results - It sounds like you do not have a problem with the query itself. That sounds great! I don't know what live objects refers to, or your settings - is this the number of objects you've read into the JVM, and it is being held onto after your query? Paging is great, but you might be using the same entityManager instance for all your pages - JPA requires they be 'managed' by the persistence unit util the EM finishes. The loops you've shown in the VehicleService doesn't make it clear what you are doing. Likely just need an em.clear()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, the issue does not seem to be with the paging query itself, but with how it is used and the amount of data affects the JVM. The code snippet provided suggests you are calling `vehicleRepository.findByType(type, pageable);` multiple times within the same VehicleService method, with the implication being they would be all within the same EntityManager/transactional context. JPA requires EntityManager contexts cache every entity read through them, so that they can monitor and serialize any changes made to the database. If you are reading in large batches of entities, that builds up - EntityManagers are meant to represent units of work and not be long lived like that.

Solution(s) would be to break up each 'batch' into its own transactional context, with a call for each vehicle type.

Alternatively, you can get a handle on the EntityManager instance. After processing your entities, call EntityManager.clear() to have it release its references to all managed entities within it, and allow them to be garbage collected if you don't have application references to them.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. I am using JPA so never thought about EntityManager under the hood. EntityManager.clear() fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Chris said something correct: It could be that you application doesn't know where it left of last time querying for "B", what happens is (pagesize 1000):

**You request page 0:**
Find matching entries and add them to the result set. Once the result set has a size of 1000, return it.

**You request page 1:**
Find (!) and skip the first 1000 matching entries. Take the matching entries 1001 to 2000, add them to the result set and ignore it.

**You request page 2:**
Find (!) and skip the first 2000 matching entries. Take the matching entries 2001 to 3000, add them to the result set and ignore it.

... and so on.

So basically the database executes the query multiple times, each time increasing the total query time because the database doesn't know where it left of last time. A solution would be to somehow pass the last-fetched id (primary key) to the query and start from there (`... AND id > :id`). Maybe you

I compiled a sample application to test your findings. In my vehicle table are currently ~723k entries. Database and application ran on my local machine (pagesize 1000):

1. Querying for A (0 entries) took about 10ms.
2. Querying for B (0 entries) took about 2200ms.
3. Querying for C (0 entries) took about 10ms.
4. Querying for D (0 entries) took about 10ms.
5. Querying for E (0 entries) took about 10ms.

So, I **cannot** reproduce your problem. Maybe you can cut down your code to be **as simple as possible** and share it with us (or find the bottleneck yourself).

I uploaded mine to [my Github repository.](https://github.com/mschallar/stackoverflow70850690)

The results were:

```
A: 185ms
B: 2139ms
B: 2007ms
B: 1863ms
B: 1930ms
C: 2ms
D: 3ms
E: 2ms
A: 1ms
B: 2020ms
B: 2044ms
B: 2006ms
B: 2053ms
B: .. same average values all over
```

And to mention one thing, if you have lots of records in your database but only a small amount of different types, the index won't help much. Some SQL optimizer might ignore the index and perform a full table scan as the index cardinality could be too low.

Comment: I tried using id > :id instead of offset, but that yields same problematic result. The code is already a simplified version of what we are doing. Thanks

Comment: You should check out my example and compare it with yours. The queries from my example don't get slower each subsequent call. Try to upload your example to github (or somewhere else) so I can take a look.